# Jquery mobile responsive table is not 100% width despite CSS styles

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Could somebody help me to identify the reason why responsive table is not full width despite the instructions?

Please check this documentation page for the problem found in the first table on the page, http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/table-reflow/.

In css it has width=100% applied, but the table is not full width.

Comment: 100% means 100% of the parent, maybe the parent has fixed width? Or what is the problem exactly?

Comment: the parent has larger width - checked in firebug

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems I found the problem. The table has this css

```
.ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive {
 display: table-row-group;
}
```

And if you remove this or change to display:table. Table starts to occupy the whole width.

Comment: I have the same problem even after removing this my width is not 100%

Comment: What happens when you change to display:table?

Comment: thanks anton, somehow i managed to do it. you can see here. www.spheretekk.com/indus

Comment: In order to avoid changing the default CSS from jquerymobile I put this code in a separate style.css .ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive {
display: table !important;
}